Safe to hard stop DIM 72552 latching relay?
I have a 775 12V DC motor with a stall current of 10A connected to a DIM 72552 latching relay with momentary start and stop buttons, as well as a 5A circuit breaker to quickly cut the connection when the current hits 10A+. My problem is my SPST stop button must be held down for ~1 seconds to completely reset the relay. However, I discovered that using an SPDT button, where the NO pin is connected to pin 85 on the relay, will instantly stop the motor and reset the relay, ie. a "hard stop".
Here are two schematics, with the "soft stop" on the left and the "hard stop" on the right:

My questions for everyone are:

Is the "hard stop" method safe, considering the risk of flyback current or shorting +12V and GND should both buttons be pushed simultaneously (hence the 20A diode)?
Am I correct in assuming the normally closed SPST button doesn't reset the relay immediately because the coil takes ~1 second to fully de-energize?


circuit 2 looks alright, there will be a large current as the motor slows down. you will need to do something to make it impossible to press both buttons at the same time.

Am I correct in assuming the normally closed SPST button doesn't reset the relay immediately because the coil takes ~1 second to fully de-energize?

Motors are capacitors storing charge as spin.  when you press stop on circuit 1 you need to wait for the motor voltage to get low enough that it can't turn the relay back on.  If you replace the motor with a lamp you will see that the relay reacts immediately.
Circuit 2 short circuits this capacitor causing the motor to slow down faster.
Both circuits can be started by spinning the motor.
